# System shutdown stopped working

Tags: 12.10, shutdown

Since last week shutdown has stopped working in my system. Either i use the shutdown menu in Unity/LightDM or use `sudo shutdown -h now` the system just locks, and i can't either use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>reisub</kbd>. Only a hard shutdown works.

If i shutdown from a tty, this is the last output i get before the system freezes:

```
umount: /run/lock: not munted
umount: /run/shm: not mounted
mount: / is busy
* Will now halt
[...] Power down.
```

After this the disk usage led turns on and i can't do anything else.

What could be the problem?

#### What i have tried

- set `acpi=force` in GRUB doesn't help;
- check for errors in the shutdown process: i get any error at all during shutdown, except the lines stated on top;
- `acpid` is installed.
- reboot/suspend works just fine!

### Edit

As seen [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1396878/) i get some warnings regarding ACPI in `/var/log/boot.log`.

Comment: `mount: / is busy`... what? You sure you didn't install any packages that might have interfered with the shutdown?

Comment: yes i have, but are all packages that should have nothing with the shutdown process: latex, vala, text editors, etc. Maybe the problem was originated by some update? I will try booting with other kernel

Comment: Also run the system updates again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a **bug**, and it is caused by no just one service, but a set of these, see [this tread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1061639) for further information.

Most likely `dnsmasq`, `dhclient`, `modem-manager` and `network-manager` are the involved services.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that worked for me

Before shutting down, click on network icon on the top system tray and uncheck "Enable Networking".

PS. I'm a linux noob. Discovered this trick from [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1061639).